# Android ScrollView leaves extra space at the bottom of page

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a scrollView that has a vertical layout as its child. This vertical layout has a background attribute. In this vertical layout I have 14 buttons stacked on top of each other. Instead of ending the background at the bottom of the last button it continues and adds on quite a bit of space which I do not want. Here is the code for the XML file.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/mainbg"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/maps"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/battingcages" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/collec"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/thebeyond" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mut"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/css" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ach"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/csite" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/crane" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/gas" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tif" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lgtf" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/pent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/slides" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/treehouse" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/space" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/fight" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button14"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tower" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: what is drawable mainbg ? is it 9.png ? drawable xml resource ? try taking it out and just setting the bg color to something like red and see what happens.

Comment: The layout is ok. Could you show a screen shot?

Comment: It was a regular .jpg but then I copied it into the draw9patch tool and saved it. No change. Here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/yghJXV9.png. Also I do not have this issue when not using scrollView and the .jpg

Comment: Also I just realized this probably looks really strange out of context but I'm making a guide for a game and these are all locations in the game. And here is what it looks like emulated for a better idea. http://i.imgur.com/M19vPAy.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap your ScrollView with another containing layout and then assign your background drawable to that layout.

EDIT:

**Another Solution**

Place your background drawable in a 'drawable-nodpi' folder. This will cause the system not to scale the image, along with the obvious caveats regarding supporting multiple display sizes.

**Explanation**

What's happening is that your background image is being scaled up to match the density of the display, this is increases the minimum height of that view, and thus the height of the ScrollView. This creates the unwanted scrolling. Putting the ScrollView in a containing layout, and assigning your background drawable it, alleviates this problem, since it will obviously not scroll. However, another possible side effect of the scaling is that it can create bitmap too large for android to display(one that exceeds 4096x4096). This will only give a warning at runtime and the bitmap won't be rendered, obviously a bad experience for your users.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/mainbg">

  <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/mainbg"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/maps"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/battingcages"/>

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/collec"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/thebeyond"/>

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/mut"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/css"/>

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/ach"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/csite"/>

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/crane"/>

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/gas"/>

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tif"/>

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/button8"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/lgtf"/>

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/button9"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/pent"/>

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/button10"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/slides"/>

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/button11"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/treehouse"/>

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/button12"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/space"/>

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/button13"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/fight"/>

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/button14"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tower"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: That worked for the most part. The only issue I have now is the buttons do not fill the width of the screen, even though the scrollView is set to fill the parent's width and as is the relative layout.